# How do I use a lasso free select tool while emulating a three button mouse?

Tags: interface, 3d-view, selection-tools

How do I use a lasso tool whilst emulating a 3-buttoned mouse?

Comment: Use Ctrl key and left mouse button

Comment: I had thought that was the answer, but it doesn't work for some reason... I presumed that my 3 button mouse emulation was the culprit, but now I don't know. Why ctrl + lmb do nothing?